# I should like to install windowsBuilder on Eclips-luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I should like to install Window_Builder plugin on Eclipse- luna, I have tried different ways that given on sites i.e go to Help>>install new software>> and try with both like [Luna](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna) as well as  "All available sites" but every time display following error

Unable to read [repository](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna)

Answer (score 1):

Help >> Eclipse Marketplace >> search for windows builder >> install

Answer (score 0):

You can try and download the pluggin as a offline .zip file and include it in your eclipse: http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php